# Loader lock detected twain

Tags: vb.net

I am using a TwainPro4.dll for scanning purposes in my VB.net application framework v3.5.

When i run my application i get the below exception, Please advise

LoaderLock was detected
Message: DLL 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC\PegasusImaging.WinForms.TwainPro4\4.0.22.0__80d669b8b606a2da\PegasusImaging.WinForms.TwainPro4.dll' is attempting managed execution inside OS Loader lock. Do not attempt to run managed code inside a DllMain or image initialization function since doing so can cause the application to hang.

Comment: Do you get this error while debugging or while running the application? While debugging means you have to change the way Visual studio handles the Loaderlock.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you mean when you debug your application you get this message. This message is important to understand. From MSDN:

> "The loaderLock managed debugging assistant (MDA) detects attempts to execute managed code on a thread that holds the Microsoft Windows operating system loader lock. Any such execution is illegal because it can lead to deadlocks and to use of DLLs before they have been initialized by the operating system's loader. "

Now, to get the application to run in debug mode you can disabled the LoaderLock MDA in Debug Exceptions interface by Pressing (Ctrl+D, E) then open Managed Debugging Assistants tree and uncheck Loader Lock.

However! This is indicative of the DLL being initialized or written improperly. As such, again from MSDN,:

> Typically, several threads inside the process will deadlock. One of those threads is likely to be a thread responsible for performing a garbage collection, so this deadlock can have a major impact on the entire process. Furthermore, it will prevent any additional operations that require the operating system's loader lock, like loading and unloading assemblies or DLLs and starting or stopping threads.
>
> In some unusual cases, it is **also possible for access violations or similar problems to be triggered** in DLLs which are called before they have been initialized.

You may want to go back to the developer of the DLL and see what their approved resolution is.

Sources

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172219
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290048%28VS.71%29.aspx